# simple exercise of unix fork understanding

Tags: unix, fork

considering the following instruction:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    fork();
```

I try to figure out the number of created process and the steps of graph creation.

so the code above is equivalent than:

```
fork();
fork();
fork();
```

The official answer to this problem is illustrated with this graph:

[image: graph]

I am not able to visualize how this graph is created.

This is how I would have drawn the graph.

1. so, the first fork will create a child copy (p2) of the parent process (p1). We have 2 process.
2. the second fork, will duplicate p1 and p2 parents, by creating child process (p3 and p4).
3. The third fork, will duplicate p1, p2, p3 and p4, by creating child process (p5, p6, p7, p8)

How can I obtain the same graph as my teacher?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want a graph similar to the official answer, try to stop thinking about how things run concurrently and instead concentrate on the generations of processes (parents, children, grandchildren and so on).

At the start, there is one process `p0`, with three forks to go. When doing those three forks, it creates `p1` with two forks to go, `p2` with one fork to go and `p3` with no forks left. Then `p0` exits (only `p1`, `p2` and `p3` remain).

We can toss away `p3` since it has no forks left, leaving just `p1` and `p2`).

Process `p1` then executes its second fork producing `p4` with one fork left, then executes the third fork making `p5` with no forks left. `p1` is now done and exits (`p2`, `p4` and `p5` remain).

Similar to `p3`, `p5` can be tossed because it has no forks left. This leaves `p2` and `p4`.

Similarly, `p2` had one fork left so it creates `p6` with no forks left. Then both `p2` and `p6` exit due to having no forks left, leaving `p4`.

Process `p4` had one fork left so it creates `p7` with no forks, and they both then exit.

By drawing the chart with the depth based on parentage rather than when processes are started (although the starting time<sup>(a)</sup> controls where the process exists horizontally at a specific depth, eg, see `p1`, `p2` and `p3`), your diagram should match the one given.

So think of it this way:

```
  Sequence within generation -------->
G
e           ______p00______
n          /       |       \
e       p01       p02       p03
r      /   \       |
a   p04     p05   p06
t    |
i   p07
o
n
|
V
```

---

<sup>(a)</sup> Keep in mind that starting time as defined here is when the process comes into existence - the order in which processes do *actual useful work* also depends on the vagaries of scheduling.

Comment: Really clear answer. Thank you, I just realized that fork() also make a copy of i, in the loop..

Comment: And to clarify even further, a spawned process inherits, apart from the code, also the value of the program counter. And that's why @paxdiablo says "two forks to go" etc.

Answer (score 1):

If we start with P0 it will generate process, P1, P2, and P3, but each process will have a different i, since at the moment of fork we have copied all the values on the stack.

generates P1 i = 0 
generates P2 i = 1 
generates P3 i = 2 
i = 3 no longer < 3

P1
generates P4 i = 1, i is set to 1 when generating P4 since right it was fork i was incremented and it was 0 before.
generates P5 i = 2,
i no longer < 3

P2
generates P6 i = 2, again i is 2 when generating P6 because it was 1 when the fork was called.
i no longer < 3

P3
i no longer < 3

P4
generates P7 i = 2
i no longer < 3

and well you get the idea....

Comment: do you understand where the graph is coming from?

Comment: Yes, I understand, I just realized that i was duplicated when fork is called..! Thank you!

Comment: no problem, its a good way to learn forks. The hardest part to understand is that forks copies the state of the process so you have to keep in mind when forks is called, all the variables are being copied as well at what ever state they are in ... the amazing part is that it copies both stack as well as heap, now thats impressive. ;)